# Sometimes the color of the navbar doesn't change in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, uinavigationbar

I am developing my [web developer portfolio](https://mrjithin.netlify.app). In that when I press the hamburger, the color of the top nav bar should also change. But sometimes in Chrome it doesn't change and I have to reload. I thought it is probably because the script didn't load. But even after waiting for a long time this bug occurs. Can anyone say why it happens and how to solve it. *Note that this color change is only for mobile nav*. The source code is available at https://github.com/mrjithin/my-portfolio/ . And the script that does this thing is available with the name ham.js in the scripts folder.
[image: The bug image]
The top color should have been the same as the color of the rest of the navbar.

```js
// ham.js
// For mobile hamburger
const mobNav = document.querySelector("nav#mobile");
const deskNav = document.querySelector("nav.desktop");
const navColor = window.getComputedStyle(mobNav).getPropertyValue("background-color");

document.getElementsByClassName("ham")[0].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("ham")[0].classList.toggle("cross");
  document.getElementById("line2").classList.toggle("none");
  mobNav.classList.toggle("on");
  mobNav.classList.toggle("off");
  if(mobNav.className === "on"){
    deskNav.style.backgroundColor = navColor;
  } else {
    deskNav.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
});

// To close the navbar on clicking a link. 
const mobileLis = document.querySelectorAll("nav#mobile a");

Array.from(mobileLis).forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("click", event => {
    document.getElementsByClassName("ham")[0].classList.toggle("cross");
  document.getElementById("line2").classList.toggle("none");
    mobNav.classList.toggle("on");
    mobNav.classList.toggle("off");
    if(mobNav.className === "on"){
      deskNav.style.backgroundColor = navColor;
    } else {
      deskNav.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this code

```
const navColor = window.getComputedStyle(mobNav).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

try this one

```
const navColor = () => window.getComputedStyle(mobNav).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

And call `navColor` as a function `navColor()`

Comment: Thank you @Oleg Barabanov can you tell why it didn't work before?

Comment: The first time you run
`const navColor = window.getComputedStyle(mobnav).GetPropertyValue("background-color")`
calculates the background once. But when the resolution changes, the background color changes, but the `navColor` constant is not updated and the old value is stored there.